# How to fill different color for one of my rectangle from my list when the mouse is hover on that particular area?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, c#-2.0, drawrectangle

I have list of rectangles if the mouse hover on the area of the rectangles located i want to change the color for the rectangle my mouse coordinate is on. I have done this but the color is not fast enough to change. The following method selects which rectangle it is.

```
    void OnMouseMoveOnTheRectangles(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF[] allRectangles = new RectangleF[aListDrawings.Count];
        aListDrawings.CopyTo(allRectangles);

        if (allRectangles.Length == 0)
            return;
        RectangleF currentSelected = RectangleF.Empty;

        foreach (RectangleF rec in allRectangles)
        {
            RectangleF current = GetOffsetRectangle(rec);

            if (current.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                _currentActive = current;
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

This is my RedDraw Function you can call it

```
    protected virtual void DrawSelection(PaintEventArgs e, RectangleF[] sRegion, 
        SolidBrush _brush)
    {
        if (sRegion.Length == 0)
            return;
        e.Graphics.SetClip(this.GetInsideViewPort(true));
        RectangleF[] offsetRectangles = new RectangleF[sRegion.Length]; 
        int x = 0;
        foreach (RectangleF r in sRegion)
        {                
            offsetRectangles[x] = this.GetOffsetRectangle(r);

            x++;
        }
        using (Brush brush = _brush)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangles(brush, offsetRectangles);
        }

        //This is where i color i tried to change the color for that particular rectangle
        if (_currentActive != RectangleF.Empty)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x90, Color.Red)),
                    _currentActive);
        }


        using (Pen pen = new Pen(this.SelectionColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(pen, offsetRectangles);
        }

        e.Graphics.ResetClip();
    }
```

Comment: How does 'not fast enough' show? Flicker? How many rectangles do you have? What type of control  are you drawing them on? Dou you use a DoubleBuffered control? Do you call the redraw from the Paint via Invalidate from the MouseMove? Do you check if it is necessary, ie if the current rectangle has changed?

Comment: Side note: `_currentActive` never gets reset to an empty rectangle.

Comment: I don't see any code here that would initiate a redraw as the mouse is moved. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem.

Comment: @taw the speed is not predictable. It doesn't flicker. I might have multiple it is dynamic. The control is a custom control based on the Control class. I don't use DoubleBuffering. Yes I call the redraw from the paint but not via Invalidate on mousmove. The current rectangle changed if I click or have too much movement on it or I minimized and maximized

Comment: So the repaint lags behind your mouse movements? - _Yes I call the redraw from the paint but not via Invalidate on mousmove_ So when and how do you trigger the paint?

Comment: Yes. I think the repaint lags from my mouse movement. The repaint is executed by the default event trigger mechanism. Every some period the paint event triggered. @Taw

Comment: Well how could that work??? The system doesn't do updates for fun all the time. __You__ need to call Invalidate on the control that needs updating __whenever__ your data have changed. So in the `MouseMove` you need to a) determine the rectangle you are over b) check if it has changed c) set the colors of the current and prevous one and then d) call Invalidate() !

Answer (score 0):

Just like @TaW says it is the Invalidate function that is going to do you the trick. It will fire the Paint event at an appropriate time and your graphics will be updated. To find invalidate any control element has it. So you can use the invalidate method found under your canvas control.